# Add column to multi dimension array Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that filters some data on Excel using Excel 2019

```
=Filter($E:$N,($F:$F > $Q$1),"")
```

Its very simple but i want to add a column to the end of the table with just some text on it but i am struggling to find a way to do this.

Any advise would be appreciated on this or a start point at least - i would rather avoid doing this in VBA if possible

I've tried google but i am not getting very far, more so i am not sure the exact terminology i should be googling to begin with.

This is my current data

```
|            | Project A            | Project B     | Project C      |
|------------|----------------------|---------------|----------------|
| 11/12/2023 | Remind PC to do this |               |                |
| 12/12/2023 |                      |               | Review meeting |
| 13/12/2023 | Start work on this   | Remember this |                |
```

And i want a table to display something off the back of this like this

```
| Date       | Description          | Project   |   |
|------------|----------------------|-----------|---|
| 11/12/2023 | Remind PC to do this | Project A |   |
| 12/12/2023 | Review Meeting       | Project C |   |
| 13/12/2023 | Remeber this         | Project B |   |
| 13/12/2023 | Start work on this   | Project B |   |
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this??

Comment: Is it a static text you want to add?

Comment: You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post something reproducible. (Sample data + expected outcome the data)

Comment: If you are using `Excel 2019` then you could use `CHOOSE()` --> `=CHOOSE({1,2},"Some Data",FILTER()")` function, however its not clear therefore adding some markdown data as mentioned above by @P.b Sir will be helpful, makesure to show the expected output as well

Comment: Can you add the new column to the original dataset (so, use Column O, and then filter E:O instead of E:N)?

Comment: Since you're referencing entire columns, it's apparent that your data are _not_ in an [Excel table](https://exceljet.net/articles/excel-tables). If you convert your data into an Excel table then you can easily do what you want, e.g. `=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Age]>$Q$1)` where `Age` is the header of the data in column F.

Comment: Ive just posted an update to my question with a table example to better explain my issue

Answer (score 0):

Using `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` functions this can be accomplished, however one can use `POWER QUERY` as well.

Excel Formula Solution:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A7</kbd>

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(A$2:A$4)-ROW(A$2)+1)/($B$2:$D$4<>""),ROWS(A$6:A6)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B7</kbd>

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,
  MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$4,0),
  AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($B$2:$D$4)-COLUMN($B$2)+1)/(($A7=$A$2:$A$4)*($B$2:$D$4<>"")),COUNTIF(A$7:A7,A7)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C7</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(REPT($B$1:$D$1,B7=$B$2:$D$4))
```

---

All the above formulas needs to be filled down!

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_One`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_One"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date"}, "Project", "Description"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Description] <> null and [Description] <> ""),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Date", "Description", "Project"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Date", type date}, {"Description", type text}, {"Project", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Alternatively sharing the `MS365` version method:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",A2:A4&"|"&B2:D4&"|"&B1:D1),2),"|",{1,2,3}),"|"), 
     IFERROR(--α, α))
```

---

Or,

```
=HSTACK(
        TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",A2:A4),2),
        TOCOL(B2:D4,1),
        TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",B1:D1),2)
        )
```

---